# Does gnome-character-map include any math symbols?

Tags: special-characters

I found **gnome-character-map** very useful application, when I need to construct simple math formula, it has greek letters, therefore I wanted to go further, does gnome-character-map have any other math symbols, **"great or equal","doesn't equal"** for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, you can simply reverse search the symbol, let's say ≥ (more or equal), find it and other symbols.

Answer (score 8):

In Character Map menu, View > By Unicode Block.

Then select "Mathematical Operators" in the list at the left.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.